# SSIS: Execute SQL Task with OUTPUT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

If to run the following code directly in SQL Server Management Studio it works, but for some reason I can't get it working with Execute SQL task in SSIS:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Tmp
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp (
  data1 nvarchar(20), 
  data2 nvarchar(50), 
  data3 nvarchar(100), 
  data4 nvarchar(100), 
  date1 datetime, 
  date2 datetime
)
delete from dbo.Mytable
OUTPUT deleted.* into dbo.Tmp
```

If to run task, the following error appears:

> Error: 0xC002F210 at Delete previous records, Execute SQL Task:
>   Executing the query "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Tmp
>
> CREATE TAB..." failed with the following error: "Incorrect syntax near
>   'OUTPUT'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
>   or connection not established correctly.

Any ideas how to get this to work properly?

Comment: please share your myTable schema

Comment: can you try removing 'from' clause as-> delete dbo.Mytable OUTPUT deleted.* into dbo.Tmp

Comment: @UmairRamzan Tried to remove "from", but it didn't help.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ - both tables have same structure and data types., thats why I use deleted.*

Comment: If the table structures are different you need to list the column names individually.

Comment: You can either do it in two stages within a transaction OR you can use a ON DELETE trigger that INSERTS the data into the new location as a reaction to the delete command that you execute.

Comment: @xXx - I am aware of it, structure is same and as I mentioned in orig. post there is no issues with the query if to execute it directly in SSMS. But I am just wondering is it somehow possible to use OUTPUT statement inside Execute SQL Task.

Comment: @Ziil I already executed the same and it is working. Can you check with your Connection ?

Comment: @Ziil, have you tried adding square brackets on your table name?